Laravel update, Put request is sent but it doesnt work
When I try to update my DB it just reloads the site and it doenst work.
When I check, the request is sent as you can see in the NetWotk tab
Here is the Network tab
But all it does is erfreshing the website but isnt updating the DB.
my Controller:
 public function edit(Rezept $rezepte)
    {
        //
        return view('rezepte.edit', ['rezepte' => $rezepte]);
    }


 public function update(UpdateRezeptRequest $request, Rezept $rezepte)
    {
        //
        $validated = $request->validated();
        $rezepte -> update($validated);
        return redirect()->route('rezepte.show', $rezepte)->withSuccess("Rezept wurde Aktualisiert");
    }


My model:
class Rezept extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;


    protected $fillable = [
        'title',
        'portion_size',
        'zutaten',
        'rezeptbeschreibung',
        'zubereitungszeit',
    ];

}

My UpdateRequest:
public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            //
            'title' => 'required',
            'portion_size' => 'required',
            'zutaten' => 'required',
            'rezeptbeschreibung' => 'required',
            'zubereitungszeit' => 'required'
        ];


       
    }

My Route:
Route::resource('/rezepte', RezeptController::class);

And my edit.blade.php:
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <form id="myform" action="{{ route('rezepte.update', $rezepte) }}" method="POST">
        @csrf
        @method("PUT")
        @if ($errors ->has('portion_size'))
        <ul class="list-group"> 
            @foreach ($errors->get('portion_size') as $error)
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-between rounded">
                    <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-danger">
                        <span class="text-danger">{{ $error }}</span>
                    </li>
                </div>    
            @endforeach
        </ul>



        @endif
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
            <div class="card " style="width: 18rem;">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="{{ $rezepte->picURL }}" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">
                        <input type="text" name="title" value="{{ $rezepte->title }}">
                    </h5>
                    <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">
                        <input type="text" name="portion_size" value="{{ $rezepte->portion_size }}">
                    </h6>
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-header">
                            Zutaten
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <p class="card-text">
                                <input type="text" name="zutaten" value="{{ $rezepte->zutaten }}" style="width: 220px">
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-header">
                            Rezept
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body" style="height: 200px">
                            <p class="card-text">
                                <textarea type="text" name="zutaten" style="height: 170px; width: 220px">{{ $rezepte->rezeptbeschreibung }}</textarea>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
    
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="d-flex justify-content-around">
                            <a href="{{ route('rezepte.index') }}" class="btn btn-secondary">Zurück</a>
                            <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="submit">speichern</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card-footer text-muted d-flex justify-content-center">
                    {{ $rezepte->updated_at }}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </form>

   
@endsection


The Problem only occures when the Request should be Succsessful.
If I intentionally leave a field Blank then the Error Massage is getting displayed see here:
Error is getting displayed
So de Validating part is working.
on an other project its working with this code except i dont use cards but thats the only difference.
Why isnt the DB not Updating ?
I already tried to put @method("PATCH") instead.
I tried putting {{ method_field('PUT') }} instead.

You're only checking for errors in the field "portion_size", I believe you may have errors in any of the other 4 fields but they are not been displayed. You should display the errors for all fields with something like this: $errors->any() instead of $errors->has('portion_size'). And change $errors->get('portion_size') for $errors->all(). Check Validation errors

The screenshot you show is missing both rezeptbeschreibung and zubereitungszeit, wihch are both required by your validation.  BTW you showed us "My UpdateRequest", but your controller is actually using UpdateRezeptRequest - is that a typo here, or are they different form request classes?

As already pointed out, you're only displaying 1 error: @foreach ($errors->get('portion_size').  If there are other errors (like missing rezeptbeschreibung and zubereitungszeit, the page will reload but the errors won't be displayed, exactly as you're seeing.  Looks like a typo.
